# Is it necessary to close the StringReader in this case?

Tags: java, xml, document, stringreader

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().
               newDocumentBuilder().
               parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Comment: No. A StringReader reads from a String in memory. There's no resource like a file descriptor to release when you're done with it.

Comment: Yes, if something implements Closeable, you should close it. You can look inside the current implementation, and say, closing it doesn't do anything helpful in this case. But encapsulation allows implementations to change. And the try-with-resources block makes it easy to close.

Comment: @AndyThomas so you always close a java.util.stream.Stream?

Comment: @JBNizet - Fine. "If something implements Closeable, you should close it -- *unless the API documentation explicitly says it's not necessary, as for Stream.*"

Comment: @JBNizet I think in this case it is appropriate to close it, it will come handy for future refactoring where the `Reader` implementation changes.

Comment: Nice questions you ask ... and welcome to upvote levels. Btw: please consider accepting helpful answers at some point in time. Like, right here ... you didnt comment on the answer, and also not accept it. Albeit the answer answers your question ... so, as said, please look into accepting answers as soon as you get one that solves your problem!

Answer (score 1):

`StringReader` extends `Reader`, which implements `Closeable`.
However, just by looking at the source code, you see what it does is basically irrelevant

```
public void close() {
    str = null;
}
```

`InputSource` doesn't implement `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable`, that means it is still the `Reader` duty to close itself. Another implementation of `Reader` might require that, however, so close it as standard.

One that might really require closing is `FileReader`, which is also acceptable by `InputSource`.